# propel orm - migration

Tags: memory, migration, diff, propel2

I have this problem and I couldn't find very good informations. For those informations I have found, none is useful. Here it goes, I started a project with propel, I created a first database with a basic table in it, ran "php propel init", everything worked fine. Then I needed another table, I created in its schema.xml, but when I run any of those migration tools I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in D:\Desenvolvimento\workspace\Login\vendor\propel\propel\bin\propel.php on line 1

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in D:\Desenvolvimento\workspace\Login\vendor\propel\propel\bin\propel.php on line 1
```

It has been very frustrating, I feel internet lacks of this propel info.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's windows 10 environment, last xampp version

Comment: It would be helpful to see your schema before and after, along with the steps and commands that you are attempting to use to preform the migration.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but figured this out. At least what I should not do

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I shouldn't manually edit the databae. Once it's created the best thing to do is use the XML to edit.